# Align Email Center Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

trying to center align my email in Outlook Web Mail, it works great in every other client, gmail, etc even the outlook office app on Mac and PC but for some reason it aligns left in the webmail, tried adding a div align center after the body tag, didn't work either.

This is my setup:

```
<body align="center" style="background: #E8E8EA; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; margin: 0 auto;padding: 0;">
<span class="preheader" style="display: none; font-size: 1px; color: #E8E8EA;">Preheader</span>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"  style="background:#E8E8EA; margin: 0 auto; text-align:center;">
  <tr>
    <td style="margin: 0 auto; text-align:center;" align="center" width="100%"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background:#E8E8EA; margin: 0 auto; min-width:600px;">
        <tr>
          <td class="wrap" align="center" valign="top" style="background:#E8E8EA;" width="100%"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td align="center"><a href="[weblink]" style="font-size:9px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#7f7f81; padding-top: 10px;">View in browser</a></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will work well if you simply replace

```
min-width:600px;
```

with

```
width:600px;
```

Comment: This also worked but it was the email client I was using to test the mail was adding code, in the end when I used a different one my original code worked fine, but your answer also worked. Thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this type formate it work in all type of webmail and outlook also

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
 <table align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse" id="Table_01" width="700" height="auto" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
           <td>
           </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```